# How can we create our own custom field in salesforce Reports?

Tags: custom-reports

How can we create our own custom field in salesfroce Reports?

Answer (score 2):

Custom fields aren't created in Reports, they're created in Objects.

Once you've created an object and fields, you can create a report to display that information either as:

> - **Tabular** - Similar to a spreadsheet, they consist simply of an ordered set of fields in columns.
> - **Summary** - Summary reports are similar to tabular reports, but also allow users to group rows of data.
> - **Matrix** - Matrix reports allow you to group records both by row and by column.
> - **Joined** - Joined reports let you create different views of data from multiple report types.

The point is that reports only *view* information and manipulate how it appears.

If, for some reason you can't see a field on a report type, chances are you haven't added it to that report type.

To add it to a report type, go to:

```
Setup > Create > Report Types
```

Then click on the Report Type you want to add fields too.

Finally, under **Fields Available for Reports** click on `Edit Layout` and add fields by clicking and dragging fields from right to left.